# Boilerplate text with Emacs Gnus

Tags: emacs, gnus

How can I make boilerplate text to use with Emacs Gnus email responses?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I would like to save three or four common responses, choose one, make small edits, and post or email the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AbbrevMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode) works in Gnus.

From that link (with some edits):

> #### Defining Abbrevs
>
> Type the word you want to use as
> expansion, and then type ‘C-x a g’ and
> the abbreviation for it. Example:
>
> This is the text of an opening paragraph.<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> 0 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd>open<kbd>Return</kbd>

*Me:* That's a zero after the `C-u`. Together they make the abbrev definition `C-x a g` apply to the selected region, which is a paragraph, in this case, which the `M-h` (`Esc-h` or `Alt-h`) selected. The abbrev definition can be made to apply only to the current major mode instead of globally by using `C-x a l` (that's an "ell" instead of the "g").

> #### Saving Abbrevs
>
> Use ‘M-x write-abbrev-file’ and just
> hit RET when asked for a filename. The
> default is “~/.abbrev_defs”. In the
> future, Emacs should save the abbrevs
> automatically when you quit Emacs.
>
> Also, if you want abbreviations to be
> saved whenever you save files (C-x s)
> or quit emacs, add the following to
> your .emacs:
>
> (setq save-abbrevs t)
>
> #### Restoring Abbrevs
>
> Use ‘M-x read-abbrev-file’ to read the
> abbrevs, or better yet, add the
> following to your ~/.emacs file:
>
> (quietly-read-abbrev-file)
>
> This will read the definitions
> from the default file,
> “~/.abbrev_defs”.
>
> #### Using Abbrevs
>
> ‘M-x abbrev-mode’ toggles Abbrev mode.
> You can also put the following in your
> ~/.emacs file if you want it always
> on:
>
> (abbrev-mode 1) Actually, you may have to do:
>
> (setq default-abbrev-mode t) I’m not really sure why.

*me again:* Once abbrev-mode is on, typing an abbreviation followed by white space causes it to be immediately expanded. However, if you don't want that to happen you can leave it turned off and expand them manually like this:

> open<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>

becomes:

> This is the text of an opening paragraph.

Comment: No, I mean Emacs Gnus.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnus

Comment: abbrev-mode works in Gnus.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [YASnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) which would allow you to tab complete parts of boiler plate text where required.

Answer (score 1):

Gnus uses Message-Mode for creating messages, so maybe that one has some specific functions for it.

I would use a custom hook in `message-setup-hook` for that (which asks me what I want to be asked and create a template). Note that this hook is called for both email and usenet news, both new messages and replies. But it should be easy to distinguish these cases from the buffer content.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, you can do something like this:

```
(setq my-F3-keymap (make-sparse-keymap))
(global-set-key [(f3)] my-F3-keymap)

(define-key my-F3-keymap [(n)]
  (function
   (lambda ()
     "insert now is..."
     (interactive)
     (insert "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country."))))

(define-key my-F3-keymap [(N)]
  (function
   (lambda ()
     "insert now is... with newlines"
     (interactive)
     (insert "Now is the time\nfor all good men\nto come to the aid\nof their country."))))

(define-key my-F3-keymap [(f)]
  (function
   (lambda ()
     "insert external file contents"
     (interactive)
     (insert-file "c:/temp/foo.html"))))
```